# NASM loop over bytes

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

Currently I'm trying to loop over every single byte in a buffer (read from a file) and compare it to see if any of them is a whitespace, and write them to STDOUT. For some reason the program compiles and runs fine, but produces zero output.

```
section .data
   bufsize dw      1024

section .bss
   buf     resb    1024
section  .text
  global  _start

_start:
    ; open the file provided form cli in read mode
    mov edi, 0
    pop   ebx
    pop   ebx
    pop   ebx
    mov   eax,  5
    mov   ecx,  0 
    int   80h
    ; write the contents in to the buffer 'buf'
    mov     eax,  3
    mov     ebx,  eax
    mov     ecx,  buf
    mov     edx,  bufsize
    int     80h

    ; write the value at buf+edi to STDOUT 
    mov     eax,  4
    mov     ebx,  1
    mov     ecx,  [buf+edi]
    mov     edx, 1
    int     80h
    ; if not equal to whitespace, jump to the loop
    cmp byte [buf+edi], 0x20
    jne loop

loop:
    ; increment the loop counter
    add     edi, 1
    mov     eax,  4
    mov     ebx,  1
    mov     ecx,  [buf+edi]
    int     80h
    ; compare the value at buf+edi with the HEX for whitespace
    cmp byte [buf+edi], 0x20
    jne loop

; exit the program
mov   eax,  1
mov   ebx,  0 
int   80h
```

Comment: 0x20 is not "whitespace", it's literally just *space*, i.e. a subset of whitespace. This is probably nit-picking, though. :)

Comment: stupid question, but are you sure there are some `0x20` in your file?

Comment: so is this 32-bit linux or is it BSD?

Comment: So you want to print characters until you find a space, and then stop? Can you supply a test input file? I don't use NASM but most of the syscalls look OK, even though you aren't checking their return codes. These open/read/write calls could be failing for whatever reason.

Even if it worked fine, if there was two spaces at the beginning of the input file you wouldn't produce any output anyway (although it'd print a single space).

Comment: The program doesn't run fine for me. I compiled and ran it through GDB  and it produced a Segmentation Fault. I'd go through and do some error checking, and then use a debugger to examine the code.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. It segfaults because it's expects a cmdline argument, sorry that I did not mention this. I already resolved the issue with help from someone on IRC. It's Linux 32bit and the file i was opening is /proc/uptime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem was that I didn't given the address of bufsize (`[bufsize]`), also the loops had some problems.

Here's the fixed version, thanks everyone for your input.

```
section .data
   bufsize dd      1024

section .bss
   buf:     resb    1024
section  .text
  global  _start

_start:
    ; open the file provided form cli in read mode
    mov edi, 0
    pop   ebx
    pop   ebx
    pop   ebx
    mov   eax,  5
    mov   ecx,  0
    int   80h
    ; write the contents in to the buffer 'buf'
    mov     eax,  3
    mov     ebx,  eax
    mov     ecx,  buf
    mov     edx,  [bufsize]
    int     80h

    ; write the value at buf+edi to STDOUT
    ; if equal to whitespace, done
loop:
    cmp byte [buf+edi], 0x20
    je done
    mov     eax,  4
    mov     ebx,  1
    lea     ecx,  [buf+edi]
    mov     edx,  1
    int     80h
    ; increment the loop counter
    add     edi, 1
    jmp loop
done:
; exit the program
mov   eax,  1
mov   ebx,  0
int   80h
```

Comment: That still contains bugs. For example, "bufsize dw" creates a 16-bit value, but you read it as a 32-bit value. Should change it to "bufsize dd" or "movzx edx,word [bufsize]". There's also no error handling (e.g. what if "open()" fails?). I'd also want to use (the equivalent of) "puts()" or "write()" for output, rather than calling the kernel for each individual character.

Comment: Valid points, thank you. Changed the code to accommodate your suggestions except for the error handling.